# Cheesecake- adding cream

Tags: baking, substitutions, cream

Would it make a difference in my cheesecake if I used liquid heavy whipping cream instead of heavy cream? ( Husbandbought the wrong thing)

Answer (score 2):

Heavy cream and heavy whipping cream are almost the same thing.  The only difference is the amount of fat they contain.  Heavy cream contains about 36% fat, while whipping cream contains only about 30%.  (That means that heavy cream actually produces better, thicker whipped cream!)

Since this is going into a cheesecake, I think that this will be an acceptable substitution.  The amount of cream included in cheesecake recipes is usually quite small, and used primarily for thinning the mixture.  Cheesecake is already high in fat, so the addition of a little more is unlikely to matter, especially in such a small quantity.  I would not expect any difference in flavor or texture in the finished cake.

Comment: „Better“ is a matter of taste, „thicker“ yes. And while for piping thicker=better, some prefer the slightly softer, creamier mouthfeel of whipping cream. Apart from this minor nitpick, I agree with you.

Comment: +1, but I agree with @Stephie that better is subjective. Here, your idea of better is opposite to mine, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the two is the fat content. If we were talking about whipping the cream and serving it directly, then there would be a small but noticeable difference in the texture, firmness and mouthfeel.

In a baked cheese cake, the difference should be insignificant and even for no-bake cheesecakes (which often use whipped cream) you should be ok with using them interchangeably.